# PHP count not working

Tags: php, count

I have an array that have the size 2:

```
Array ( [0] => VP/vnyAf8TuTENi6xQr1a7ZUg+LtJitd1TwUHCuqSmSqRM1EGDaGkArssU7Ag/aZzwjuIPvQ3wGskhs0b85j2ANnX3KZ4JUTMwcMMAI0eXd+FO5wjZLWfhOa1gyhIwhD [1] => e0k59g4lqV/AcJRE9apOlem3mT4lNuG0TJhfFcypZ6HR7bAnUxrstxz/JdAQLeb/E4+0pfYmiIuqr4N+O3L1RDvSIKXA3J/ubOKmiz+Yo5Vz5ml91VZ1DR8eHWaP1vE9 )

echo count($credentials);
```

This prints: 2

But somehow for the following code I enter in the first condition and "a" is printed

```
if(count($credentials !== **2**)){
    echo "a";
} else {
    echo "b";
}
```

If I change the code as:

```
if(count($credentials == **32**)){
    echo "a";
} else {
    echo "b";
}
```

It still prints "a".

Can someone explain whats is wrong here?

Comment: What does `**2**`  means? And how did you get count 2 from single valued array that's strange over here

Comment: Nice decoration of number by `**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition code is total wrong, try below:-

```
if(count($credentials) !== 2){
    echo "a";
} else {
    echo "b";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well your code is wrong because: "!==" does not mean NOT, It should be like this:

```
if(count($credentials) != 2){
    echo "a";
} else {
    echo "b";
}
```

Because "==" Means something else, please try now, if not will try something else :)

Comment: !== is a strict DOES NOT EQUAL comparison.